# How can I pass complex expression to parametrized active pattern?

Tags: f#, active-pattern

I defined the active pattern "Expression" as follows:

```
let (|Expression|_|) expression _ = Some(expression)
```

Now I'm trying to use it in this way:

```
match () with
| Expression((totalWidth - wLeft - wRight) / (float model.Columns.Count - 0.5)) cw
    when cw <= wLeft * 4. && cw <= wRight * 4. ->
        cw
| Expression((totalWidth - wLeft) / (float model.Columns.Count - .25)) cw
    when cw <= wLeft * 4. && cw > wRight * 4. ->
        cw
| Expression((totalWidth - wRight) / (float model.Columns.Count - .25)) cw
    when cw > wLeft * 4. && cw <= wRight * 4. ->
        cw
| Expression(totalWidth / float model.Columns.Count) cw
    when cw > wLeft * 4. && cw > wRight * 4. ->
        cw
| _ -> System.InvalidProgramException() |> raise
```

But this results in "error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '-' in pattern". Is that fixable?

What am I trying to do is to write clearly a solution to the following equation:

max(wl - cw * .25, 0) + max(wr - cw * .25) + cw * columnCount = ActualWidth

where cw is the only variable.

Can you suggest any better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The langauge of expressions that can be used as arguments for parameterized active patterns is limited in some ways. As far as I can tell, the [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf) doesn't say that explicitly, but the grammar suggests that it must be possible to parse the *argument expression* as `pat-param` (page 90):

> pat-param :=
>           | const
>           | *long-ident*
>           | [ *pat-param* ; ... ; *pat-param* ]
>           | ( *pat-param*, ..., *pat-param* )
>           | *long-ident* *pat-param*
>           | *pat-param* : *type*
>           | <@ *expr* @>
>           | <@@ *expr* @@>
>           | null

So, I think you'll need to write your pattern matching differently. You could turn the expressions into ordinary arguments of the `match` construct and write something like this:

```
match 
  (totalWidth - wLeft - wRight) / (float model.Columns.Count - 0.5),
  (totalWidth - wLeft) / (float model.Columns.Count - .25),
  (totalWidth - wRight) / (float model.Columns.Count - .25)
with
| cw1, _, _ when cw1 <= wLeft * 4. && cw1 <= wRight * 4. -> cw1
| _, cw2, _ when cw2 <= wLeft * 4. && cw2 > wRight * 4. -> cw2
| _, _, cw3 when cw3 > wLeft * 4. && cw3 <= wRight * 4. -> cw3
| _ -> totalWidth / float model.Columns.Count
```

If the pattern used in the expression is always the same, you could also use active pattern like:

```
let (|Calculate|) w p _ =
  (totalWidth - w) / (float model.Columns.Count - p)
```

... and then write something like:

```
let wDif = wLeft - wRight
match () with
| Calculate wDif 0.5 cw -> cw
| Calculate wLeft 0.25 cw -> cw
// .. etc.
```

Comment: so is it impossible use composite functions as an argument for the active pattern? e.g. we cannot do `| MyActive (myfuna>>myfunb) x -> ...` we can only do let `myfun = myfuna>>myfunb ... | MyActive myfun x -> ...`

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct - you cannot directly use any complex expressions.