# In F#, how to use active expressions to check type variables

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

The use of type `typedef<typename>` as a literal target within a match expression or when supported by an active expression as shown here shows syntax error on the `typeof<>` portion of the expression. Am I doing something wrong?

(Note that the match is against an instance of `Type` and not an actual value of that type.)

```
let (|IsType|_|) (et:Type) t = if et.Equals(t) then Some() else None

let someFunc someType =
    match someType with
    | IsType (typeof<string>) _ -> "Yes"
    | _                         -> "No"
```

Interestingly, within an `if..then` expression it does work.

```
let someFunc someType =
    if typeof<string> = someType then "Yes"
    else "No"
    )
```

This circumstance would appear to be an oversight in the language.

Comment: check this out [F# equivalent of `is` keyword in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677345/f-equivalent-of-is-keyword-in-c)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779602/use-of-typeof-in-active-pattern.

Comment: I guess you're already aware of `:?`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a restriction of the F# language syntax - the things that can appear in a pattern (even when it is an active pattern) have to be syntactically patterns. So you can write `IsSomething 123` because `IsSomething` and `123` are valid patterns, but you cannot write `IsType typeof<Foo>` because `typeof<Foo>` cannot be parsed as a pattern.

One workaround is to pass the argument as a quotation - I would probably not do this because it looks uglier and it is slower than doing a normal `if`, but it works:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let (|IsType|_|) (et:Expr<'T>) (t:System.Type) = 
  if t.Equals(typeof<'T>) then Some() else None

let someFunc someType =
    match someType with
    | IsType <@ Unchecked.defaultof<string> @> -> "Yes"
    | _ -> "No"
```

It uses `Unchecked.defaultof` just to get a quotation of type `string` - but you could provide any other quotation of the type, so `IsType <@ "nada" @>` would work too.

**EDIT:** In the F# language specification, the allowed syntax is defined in section 7:

```
pat-param :=
    | const 
    | long-ident 
    | [ pat-param ; ... ; pat-param ]
    | ( pat-param, ..., pat-param )
    | long-ident pat-param 
    | pat-param : type
    | <@ expr @>
    | <@@ expr @@>
    | null
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Yet, isn't, `typeof<someType>` a `constant` and "should" be available in such context like all literals presumably are?

Comment: I added the relevant bits of the F# specification, but I completely agree that this would make sense to add. You can suggest it at: http://fslang.uservoice.com

Comment: I will. Indeed, typeof<*> and typedefof<*> are `const`. Perhaps an upper case version could be coined: `Typedef` and `TypeDefOf`, respectively.

Comment: checked the comments. Some already suggested the idea and it was rejected: (http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5664335-allow-pattern-matching-on-types#comments).

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to use the `when` class to perform a dynamic test as demonstrated here:

```
match typeValue with
    | t when t = typeof<string> -> ...
    | t when t = typeof<int> -> ...
    ...
```